# Keeping size fixed even If td has large content inside it

Tags: html, css, asp.net

[image]

In the Calendar Widget for the fourth row there is large text so its not fitting in single line so its size is increasing & View All button  is also overlapping the edge of the widget. the number of row is fixed that means it can show maximum 5 rows at a time but the content of each row may have larger text. so when its not fitting in single line its giving me the trouble. i have tried few css trick but did not work. i need help to fix the size of its content so the designs works well.I am dot net developer but not a designer so not so much expert with css design. Please help me .

This is my aspx Code.

```html
<table style="border: 0px; width: 500px;">
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 55px;"><img alt="" src="/Images/DeptIcons/Administration.png" /></td>
        <td class="deptHeader">Calendar Editor</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <hr style="border-top: 1px solid #79767b; margin-bottom: 20px;" />
    <div style="position: relative;"><img alt="" src="/Images/ctnrTop.png" /></div>
    <div style="background-image: url('/Images/ctnrBG.gif'); position: relative; margin-top: -5px; padding: 15px 0px 0px 15px;" class="cntrFont">
        <table width="927" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnRebind" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button UseSubmitBehavior="false" ID="btnRebind" runat="server" Style="display: none; width: 0px; height: 0px;
 border: none; font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px;" OnClick="btnRebind_Click" />

              <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="4" align="right"><input type="button" onclick="addResult()" value="Add Calendar Event" class="fancyButton" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width: 30px; text-align: center;"></td>
                  <td style="width: 180px;"><b>Event Name</b></td>
                  <td style="width: 160px;"><b>Event Date</b></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
                <asp:Repeater ID="rptEvents" runat="server">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 30px; text-align: center;"><img src="../Images/icoStar.png" style="width: 15px; height: 15px; margin-top: 4px;" alt="Event" /></td>
                        <td><a class="calendarName" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick='showSearchResult(<%#Eval("CalID")%>,1);'><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "calEvent")%></a></td>
                        <td><%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("calEventDate").ToString()).ToString("MMMM dd yyyy") %></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>                  
                  </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

```
<table style="border: 0px; width: 500px;">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 55px;"><img alt="" src="/Images/DeptIcons/Administration.png" /></td>
    <td class="deptHeader">Calendar Editor</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr style="border-top: 1px solid #79767b; margin-bottom: 20px;" />
<div style="position: relative;"><img alt="" src="/Images/ctnrTop.png" /></div>
<div style="background-image: url('/Images/ctnrBG.gif'); position: relative; margin-top: -5px; padding: 15px 0px 0px 15px;" class="cntrFont">
    <table width="927" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnRebind" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button UseSubmitBehavior="false" ID="btnRebind" runat="server" Style="display: none; width: 0px; height: 0px;
```

border: none; font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px;" OnClick="btnRebind_Click" />

```
          <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
              <td colspan="4" align="right"><input type="button" onclick="addResult()" value="Add Calendar Event" class="fancyButton" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="width: 30px; text-align: center;"></td>
              <td style="width: 180px;"><b>Event Name</b></td>
              <td style="width: 160px;"><b>Event Date</b></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptEvents" runat="server">
              <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 30px; text-align: center;"><img src="../Images/icoStar.png" style="width: 15px; height: 15px; margin-top: 4px;" alt="Event" /></td>
                    <td> <div title="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "calEvent")%>" style="width: 180px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis"><a class="calendarName" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick='showSearchResult(<%#Eval("CalID")%>,1);'><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "calEvent")%></a></div></td>
                    <td><%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("calEventDate").ToString()).ToString("MMMM dd yyyy") %></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>                  
              </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: well if you want to show all the text, regardless of how long it is, either you make the `div` containing the `text` bigger ( wider ) , either you make the text smaller ( `font-size` )

Comment: Or try adding style `overflow: hidden` if you don't need to show the entire text :)

Comment: You should not use tables for this.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at combining the `text-overflow: ellipsis` css rule with `overflow: hidden`. For this to work, the cell must also have a fixed width, and the `whitespace: nowrap` tells it not to wrap long text. This will show there's more text, and you can set the cell title to the full text content so a mouseover will hint the name of the entry. Please use external css files. I just put this inline as an example.

```
           <asp:Repeater ID="rptEvents" runat="server">
              <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 30px; text-align: center;"><img src="../Images/icoStar.png" style="width: 15px; height: 15px; margin-top: 4px;" alt="Event" /></td>
                    <td title="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "calEvent")%>" style="width: 300px;  white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis"><a class="calendarName" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick='showSearchResult(<%#Eval("CalID")%>,1);'><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "calEvent")%></a></td>
                    <td><%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("calEventDate").ToString()).ToString("MMMM dd yyyy") %></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>                  
              </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

**EDIT:** Sorry, My mistake... those css rules won't apply to a `<td>`. You may want to start considering dropping tables entirely in favour of `<div>`s, or insert a `<div>` into the cell, like below:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 0;
}

td:first-of-type {
  width: 30px;
}

.event-name {
  max-width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;  
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><i class="fa fa-star"></i></td>
        <td><div title="This is a very loooooooong text! There can be nothing longer than it" class="event-name">This is a very loooooooong text! There can be nothing longer than it</div></td>
        <td>Friday, August 19, 2016</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: answer edited. I forgot we were dealing with a table. You may want to consider dropping the use of tables...

Comment: your answer looks good but i don't know why its not working for me !
even i wrapped that <a> inside div but while inspecting element the div is not shown there.

Comment: notice there's a `div` embedded in the table cell. If you want to continue using inline styles, copy the `.event-name` rules from the css block and add it as a `style` attribute on the `div` within the cell. If after this, it's still not working for you, then the problem is spiritual. LOL

Comment: update your question with the latest code, so I can see what you're doing wrong

Comment: edited the question.



<td> <div title="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "calEvent")%>" style="width: 180px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis"><a class="calendarName" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick='showSearchResult(<%#Eval("CalID")%>,1);'><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "calEvent")%></a></div></td>

Comment: can it be arranged like that so that if the any rows has 2 lines then the text font size will shrink to fit in td size?

Comment: what does `<a class="calendarName">...</a>` contain (as per css rules)?

Comment: .calendarName
{
 font-family: Helvetica, Verdana;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #74ac44; 
}

Comment: Sadly, I can't help any further unless I'm able to inspect your source in chrome dev tools to see what css is conflicting with it. Do you have this hosted online yet? You may want to open and inspect that `<div>` in chrome dev tools, so you can see what css overrides mine

Comment: hmmm i understand . :( thanks for your time by the way. currently my only workaround is to use smaller font (11 instead of 12 )  to fit in 1 line. 2 lines creates problem.

Comment: You're welcome. The font-size solution is not guaranteed to work for all lengths of text. You may need to keep reducing till it becomes invisible. Unless of course, you know the maximum length of content to expect in that cell.